# cdata in xslt for html

Tags: xslt, cdata

I have an XSLT file generating plain HTML. I need to wrap some elements in CDATA blocks, so intend to use cdata-section-elements. But, if the element I want to have contain CDATA is only one `<p>` on the page, how do I get it to not put CDATA in all the other `<p>` elements?

The input data is this:

```
<item>
  ...
  <g:category>Gifts under &amp;pound;10</g:category>
</item>
```

My XSL is:

```
<xsl:element name="a">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">productlist.aspx</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:copy-of select="text()" />
</xsl:element>
```

I want this to render something like:

```
Gifts under £10
```

But all I get is:

```
Gifts under &pound;10
```

Comment: Which `<p>` tag do you want to target? Could you post some sample code?

Comment: The obvious question is: why do you want to wrap some elements in CDATA? Functionally, you should get exact same behavior from plain escaping (which XSLT will already do), only it may be somewhat larger. Are you doing it only to reduce the output size?

Comment: No, I'm doing it because the RSS feed I'm parsing has elements like &reg; in it, which I need to render properly.

Comment: If it has character entities (not elements) like `&reg;` in it, then surely the XML parser that loaded input XML for the XSLT transform processed them appropriately already? It would help if you'd be more specific about what goes wrong for you such that you think you need CDATA. From your last comment, I strongly suspect that the real problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well assuming you have some way of targeting the `<p>` tag that you want to enclose in CDATA section, you could do something like:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" 
    indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p[@test = 'test']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In this case all `<p>` tags with an attribute test = 'test' will have CDATA applied to them, all other tags will just be output as normal.

Comment: Not *nice*, but workable, +1. I wonder why anyone would want to output certain elements as CDATA, and others of the same kind not - after all, the *data* is exactly the same, so why care for the serialized representation?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this isn't working for me. The unusual characters are still being rendered but now with a trailing ]]>

Comment: Probably your problem can't be solved with CDATA then. What characters are being displayed incorrectly?

Comment: It makes sense - after all, the templates invoked by `<xsl:apply-templates/>` do not know that their output will end up in a middle of CDATA generated by `disable-output-escaping` (there's no obligation for XSLT processor to figure it out), and therefore if a template outputs `&`, for example, it will escape it to `&amp;` - and then that will end up inside CDATA.

Answer (score 0):

The code I have is:

```
<xsl:element name="a">
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    product.aspx?prod=<xsl:copy-of select="title/text()" />
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
  <xsl:copy-of select="g:price" /> - <xsl:copy-of select="title/text()" />
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: For some reason I don't understand, the code is rendering a "greater than" character just after the <![CDATA[

Comment: Can you edit your question, rather than posting this as an answer? Also, it is hard to say anything about your expectations without seeing the input data as well.