# wso2 ESB xslt transformation issue

Tags: wso2-esb

I am hoping that somebody can give some guidance with an xslt issue I am having. I am recieving a generic XML message into a proxy service, I then need to wrap the xml in a soap message and forward it on to an axis2 jms service.

I have tested the stylehseet against my xml using both a saxon and xalan engine and they both work as expected but wso2 will not accept it I get an error WstxParsingException: String ']]>' not allowed in textual content if I have the CDATA section (which I need).

any advice would be much appreciated
thanks
Paul

The stylesheet is as follows

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"     xmlns:klr="http://klr.com">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" cdata-section-elements="klr:legaldocument"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:klr="http://klr.com">
            <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                <klr:Hypertext>
                    <klr:legaldocument>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
                    </klr:legaldocument> 
                 </klr:Hypertext>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name(.)}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just your second template does not work. Here is the working complete stylesheet:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:klr="http://klr.com">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" cdata-section-elements="klr:legaldocument"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:klr="http://klr.com">
            <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                <klr:Hypertext>
                    <klr:legaldocument>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
                        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
                    </klr:legaldocument> 
                </klr:Hypertext>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[For more information see this entry here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650356/cdata-in-xslt-for-html)

Comment: thanks. that I am afraid didnt work either. the result was identical and actually when I sun it through my sax engine it produces duplicate cdata sections. I did manage to get some form of success byt removing cdata-section-elements from xsl:output. but what is very confusing now is that there is some form of axis soap wrapper on the cdat section that I am assuming is being ut there by wso2esb but I am not sure

Comment: my output was `code` <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:klr="http://klr.com"><SOAP-ENV:Body>
<klr:Hypertext>
<klr:legaldocument>
&lt;soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
&lt;soapenv:Body>
&lt;axis2ns3:text xmlns:axis2ns3="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">&amp;lt;Test/&amp;gt;&lt;/axis2ns3:text>
&lt;/soapenv:Body>
&lt;/soapenv:Envelope></klr:legaldocument>
</klr:Hypertext>
</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope> `code`

Comment: please excuse the spelling of the previous post. fried brain.

Comment: It seems to me that not one of my stylesheets behaves the same in wso2esb as it does in a standard java test environment (or indeed xmlspy or carbon studio for that matter). I have to assume that I have configured something wrong somewhere. I cant believe that its supposed to be this hard to implement. I just tried to do a simple tag rename on a response message. the tests work perfectly but through wso2esb its like nothing at all has happened.. really strange.

Comment: Which version of the WSO2 ESB are you using? Can you post a sample input file?

Comment: both 4.0.3 and 4.5.0 yield the same results. it seems the test data seems to have no bearing really. I can send test and I get the same result.

Comment: here is a super basic xslt to change the name or the response tag from an axis2 service.. the result after the xslt mediator is unchanged.. like it doesnt find the tag to change `code`<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="http://klr.com">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns:return">
        <ns:Document><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></ns:Document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>`code`

Comment: It turned out to be an issue with the ContentType on the JMS message. It wasnt being parsed properly up front so it was going through th sequence as raw text.

Comment: Oh yes - you really have to get the input file with content-type = application/xml or similar (depend on your axis2.xml). Hope the transformation now works?